# Bluebird with Lambda not returning data

Tags: node.js, lambda, promise, bluebird, serverless-framework

We have a simple query to fetch information from our database using a serverless application deployed on nodejs. Unfortunately I am not able to get any responses from Bluebird promise - the response always timesout and I'm not sure what could be causing the issue. Below are my files:

**serverless.yml:**

```
service: myAuth0

provider:
  name: aws
  iamRoleARN: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/test-role
  runtime: nodejs4.3
  stage: production
  region: us-us-1
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface"
        - "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces"
        - "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
      Resource: "*"
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - ${self:custom.${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}.${opt:region, self:provider.region}.vpc.securitygroup}
    subnetIds:
      - ${self:custom.${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}.${opt:region, self:provider.region}.vpc.subnet1}
      - ${self:custom.${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}.${opt:region, self:provider.region}.vpc.subnet2}

custom:
  production:
    us-east-1:
      vpc:
        subnet1: subnet-11111111
        subnet2: subnet-22222222
        securitygroup: sg-33333333

functions:
  getUserRoles:
    handler: app/handler.handle
    events:
      - http:
          method: get
          path: userstest/roles
```

**handler.js:**

```
'use strict';

require('dotenv').config();
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var getConn = require('./dbConn');

module.exports.handle = (event, context, callback) => {
  Promise.using(getConn(), function(conn){
    return conn.query('select ert.name from emp_roles ert order by ert.name').then(function(rows){
      let roles = [];
      rows.forEach(function(row){
        roles.push(row.name);
      });
      return roles;
    }).catch(function(err){
      console.log(error);
    });
  }).then(function(roles){
    console.log("found roles: " + roles);
    callback(null, {roles: roles});
  });
};
```

**dbConn.js:**

```
var mysql = require('promise-mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host     : process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
  user     : process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  password : process.env.MYSQL_PW,
  database : process.env.MYSQL_DB
});

function getConn() {
  return pool.getConnection().disposer(function(connection) {
    pool.releaseConnection(connection);
  });
}

module.exports = getConn;
```

I added console log entries and I can see that it completes them...however it does not return anything and I end up with a connection error. I see that the data is fetched and Lambda just sits there without returning anything for 6 seconds. Below is the latest entry from cloud watch:

> 18:15:01 START RequestId: 195a7218-a516-11e6-b52d-5f028bb2bdf6
>   Version: $LATEST 18:15:01 2016-11-07T18:15:01.820Z
>   195a7218-a516-11e6-b52d-5f028bb2bdf6 found roles: 9 18:15:07 END
>   RequestId: 195a7218-a516-11e6-b52d-5f028bb2bdf6 18:15:07 REPORT
>   RequestId: 195a7218-a516-11e6-b52d-5f028bb2bdf6 Duration: 6002.14 ms
>   Billed Duration: 6000 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 18 MB
>   18:15:07 2016-11-07T18:15:07.468Z 195a7218-a516-11e6-b52d-5f028bb2bdf6
>   Task timed out after 6.00 seconds

Is there something that breaks when using Bluebird with Lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluebird definitely works.

I think there might be a problem with ending connection using disposer. I use postgresql promise library so can't really try with mysql but I rewritten it to use disposer and I get same timeout.

Try ending connection in your finally block.

```
db.getConnection()
  .then(doMyQuery)
  .catch(catchErrors)
  .finally(db.disposeConnection)
```

EDIT: Ok, actually releasing connections is bad in lambdas, you should be ending them. mysqljs docs say:

> When you are done with a connection, just call connection.release()
>   and the connection will return to the pool, ready to be used again by
>   someone else.

You don't really want that. That's why you get a timeout. When your promise chain ends, the connection returns to the pool and WAITS to be used again, thus lambda timeouts since it's never ending.

Use connection.end() or connection.destroy()

Comment: Thanks...unfortunately it still times out at the callback (cb):
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var pool = require('./dbConn');
module.exports.handle = (event, context, cb) => {
  pool.getConnection().then(function(conn){
    conn.query(query).then(function(rows){
      let roles = [];
      rows.forEach(function(row){
        roles.push(row.name);
      });
      cb(null, {roles: roles});
    }).catch(function(err){
      console.log(error);
    }).finally(function(){
      pool.releaseConnection(conn);
    });
  }).catch(function(e){
    callback(e);
  });
};

Comment: What about your new dbConn, how that looks? EDIT: I guess it just returns a pool now.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  That did it!

Comment: @DavidD glad to help. Can you tell me if it's working for you with disposer or no? Because I'm curious why I get a timeout when I end connection in disposer.

Comment: Actually it did work with the disposer, however as you identified the problem with releasing the connection.  My connection method now is the following:
function getConn() {
  return pool.getConnection().disposer(function(connection) {
    connection.destroy(); //Works well
    //pool.releaseConnection(connection); //Timesout
  });
}

Comment: I see. I must have some bug in my disposer function.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just a note about the accepted answer:
It is not recommended to release a db connection using the finally block. In case something breaks in the lifecycle of the promise chain, there is a chance `finally` may not be called leading to resource leaks. This is documented in bluebird docs: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/resource-management.html